# Why it add `ever` in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I know a sentence:

```
Can you ever forgive me?
```

but what's the difference between this?

```
Can you forgive me?
```

why there add `ever` there? is it make emphasis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ‘ever’ it means: I understand that you do not forgive me *now*, but can you imagine that there will ever come a time when you will forgive me?

Without ‘ever’, the sentence is not wrong, but it is less idiomatic.

Comment: Or removing 'ever' from the explanation: ... "but can you imagine there may be a time when you will forgive me?"